# pass array (dynamic) data into charts.js with laravel 5.5

Tags: arrays, chart.js, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

Pass array data (dynamically) to chart.js using laravel, this "data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],"which holds numbers should contain info from database.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};

function adddata(){
    myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[7] = 60;
  myLineChart.data.labels[7] = "Newly Added";
  myLineChart.update();
}

var option = {
    showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options:option
});
```

**I am testing the data from database and l know that my array contains data but when it comes to show in chart.js is blank**

Comment: Post your controller method that you are using to pass data to the blade file. Are you passing an array or a collection? It should be a simple foreach loop but I need to see what data you are passing first.